# No operator ">>" matches these operands operand types are: std::istream >> double

Tags: c++, complex-numbers, non-member-functions

For my project I'm trying to create a free function for a complex number class. It is defined in the cpp file. The function is an overloaded input streaming operator but I keep getting the error

```
No operator ">>" matches these operands operand types are: std::istream >> double
```

on the lines

```
in >> z.real();
in >> z.imag();
```

I made a file called `complex.h` that contains the `complex` class and the two overloaded operators I want to work,  constructors for complex numbers (not sure if needed but included), and two getter methods to retrieve the real and imaginary parts of the complex class. This reproduces the error.

The declarations of the member functions are dictated by my project spec. Their return types cannot be changed.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class complex {

private://may include private helper functions
    double realX = 0;
    double imaginaryY = 0;

public:// interface for operators and member functions (methods)
    //**********************Constructors***************************
    complex() {}
    complex(double x) {
        realX = x;
    }
    complex(double x, double y) {
        realX = x;
        imaginaryY = y;
    }
    complex(const complex& z) : realX(z.realX), imaginaryY(z.imaginaryY) { //copy constructor
    }
    double real() const {
        return realX;
    }
    double imag() const {
        return imaginaryY;
    }
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, complex& z) {
    in >> z.real();
    in >> z.imag();
    return in;
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const complex& z) {
    output << "(" << z.real()
        << ", " << z.imag()
        << "i)";
    return output;
}
```

Comment: but... [std::complex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) already exists? The `using namespace std;` is confusing here - I recommend not using `using namespace std;`. Please post an [MCVE].

Comment: *complex variables z.real() and z.imag()* These are not variables. Look at them: `double real() const` Does this look like a variable to you?

Comment: One question per stackoverflow.com question, please. Do you want to ask about your failing `>>` overload, or your unary helper functions? They are two completely separate issues.

Comment: One moment I will post a smaller example of the issue I am having, and my question is now limited to just getting the istream to work, we can forget about the unary examples.

Comment: responding to the "complex variables z.real() and z.imag()", youre right my bad I mean they are functions to get the real and imaginary part of a complex number. I'm trying to get them to be inputs for the istream. I know other methods show how we can overload the istream by having the overloads be friend functions but in this case they need to be free functions so I think im stuck with using z.real()

Comment: "riend functions but in this case they need to be free functions" friend functions are free functions

Comment: responding to @KamilCuk, without including "using namespace std;" I get an error on both o and istream functions that says "identifier ostream is undefined" I thought including iostream would fix this but it does not

Comment: That's why use `std::ostream` and `std::istream` if you want them

Comment: @KamilCuk ah, that does work, thanks. I still get an error with the operands it seems but at least I know now I dont need to include namespace std

Comment: ok sounds good @JaMiT

Comment: @JaMiT is this what you guys wanted in a minimal reproducible example

Comment: `in >> z.real()` makes little sense - how can you _assign_ to a result? It's like assigning to a result of a calculation. And `comples::real()` takes a `const` object - how do you expect to modify a `const` object? The solution is adding a `imag()` and `real()` overloads for non-`const` objects that return references (or alternatively objects) to underlying variables.

Comment: @KamilCuk that does make sense but "double real() const" is how its defined in the specifications for my project. But what you said at the end, "adding a imag() and real() overloads for non-const objects" could be the solution, because in my specification I also see overloads for real() and imag() that are not const. Which might mean I have been paying attention to the wrong real() and imag() the whole time. EDIT I am mistaken, the overloaded real() and imag() functions in the spec are defined to carry a constant reference to the object double real(const complex& z)

Comment: @Muu The example looks good, but it should have been integrated into the question. (If someone is interested in the question history, they can click the "edited [time]" link.) I've made a stab at consolidation.

Comment: You might find [A: Operator Overloading Error: no match for 'operator>>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48694081/operator-overloading-error-no-match-for-operator/48694209#48694209) informative, even though it does not quite look like a duplicate to me. That other question started a step closer to a solution (it uses the `friend` keyword) than your current code.

Comment: @JaMiT thank you for this link, I will look into this

Comment: `z.real()` is not a function. It's a number. Just like `2+2` is not a function.

Comment: [The following:     double& real() {
        return realX;
    }
    double& imag() {
        return imaginaryY;
    }](https://godbolt.org/z/1h7Kzc) compiles fine

Comment: @KamilCuk dang yours does work, it seems double& real() allows the istream overload to work and double real() const allows the ostream overload to work. The only issue is my project spec requires double real() const to be a member function, double& real() isnt allowed to be a member function, and double real(const complex& z) is the only free funtion allowed, the same goes for imag(). But your code works so knowing this should help in getting closer to a solution so thank you very much for this

Comment: @KamilCuk it seems if my free function double real(const complex& z) returned a reference to a double like your double& real() does, my program would compile and fit the spec, but the spec only gives me double real(const complex& z) and not double& real(const complex& z), im not sure if the professor intended this or if its a typing mistake. I do wonder why double& real(const complex& z) works and not double real(const complex& z)

Comment: So why not just `double a, b; cin>>a>>b; return complex(a, b);`??

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> No operator ">>" matches these operands operand types are: std::istream >> double
> ```

This might seem like a strange error message. After all, one could fairly quickly come up with an example program that streams a `double` from `std::cin`, which is a `std::istream`. So what is wrong here?

The answer comes in that mess of notes that follows this error message. (Yes, it can be an intimidating mess, but the notes are there to help diagnosing the problem. No, I do not expect the entire mess to be copied into the question, since it is large and most of it is not relevant.) Somewhere in the list of candidate operators is

> ```
> operator>>(double& __f)
> ```

This is the operator that allows streaming a `double`. However, note the type of the parameter – it is not `double`, but `double&`. The target of the stream must name a variable, not merely provide a value. In your case, attempting `in >> z.real()` is similar to attempting `in >> 3.1`. The types of `z.real()` and `3.1` are both `double`, so what you can do to one you can do to the other. Hopefully you do not believe you can change mathematics by streaming a new value into `3.1`. Similarly, you cannot stream a value into a function that returns a `double`.

One solution is to make your function return what the stream operator expects, as in `double& real()` (add an ampersand and remove `const`). However, providing a public non-const reference to a private member destroys encapsulation; the member might as well be public at that point. Plus, your project does not allow it. Let's look for a better approach.

A more common solution is to make `operator>>` a `friend` of your class so that it can set the private members. This requires adding the line

```
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, complex& z);
```

to your class definition. After that is done, your implementation of `operator>>` can access the private data members, bypassing the accessor functions. Note: the definition of `operator>>` can stay right where it is, outside the class definition, if that is desirable.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, complex& z) {
    in >> z.realX;
    in >> z.imaginaryY;
    return in;
}
```

A more roundabout approach uses construction and assignment instead of friendship. This might reduce code duplication in more complex cases. However, in your case it triggers a warning because your class violates the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) by having a copy constructor but no assignment operator. Still, your explicit copy constructor is what the compiler would automatically generate for you. You could address the warning by commenting out your copy constructor.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, complex& z) {
    double real;
    double imaginary;
    
    in >> real;
    in >> imaginary;
    z = complex{real, imaginary};
    
    return in;
}
```

For something as simple as your `complex` class, I would go with friendship.

Comment: Yes, I amused myself by saying something named `complex` is simple. :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have solved by just add following include.

```
#include <sstream> 

ostringstream ss;
ss << "SOCKET #" << sock << ":" << buf << "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which IDE you use, but in my case with exact same problem the solution was to `#include <istream>`... I'm using CLion Nova Build #CL-233.13871. Hope it helps!